# When using DSE Search, Do I need to reindex to remove a field

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm using DSE Search 3.2.1. We have removed some unneeded indexes and fields and posted the `schema.xml` document to all of the nodes.  Do we need to do anything else to have it discontinue indexing data?  Do we need to run a reindex, or a full reindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure from what I see in Solr you need to reindex after changing the fields in the documents in your solr schema.xml. After you post it, you'll need to reload the core. If querying still works after that you *might* be ok, but I would guess you're going to need to run a reindex to be safe.

Comment: what do you mean by "reload the core" also, can I just do an in-place index or do i need to drop and recreate the whole index which will lead to missed reads ?

Comment: When I say reload I mean this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin (under the RELOAD action). Because the index structure is different you'll probably need to recreate the whole index unless there's some magic there for deleting fields I'm not aware of.

Comment: DSE has specific parameters that need to be used to reindex: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.2/solutions/dse_search_upload#reloading-a-solr-core

Answer (score 1):

If you don't reindex, the existing Solr index field values will remain, occupying space and responding to queries. And fresh inserts or updates will not have the deleted fields. As Ben said, that might be okay.

A Solr reindex will delete all of the old field values.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you change anything in schema.xml and want the changes to reflect you have to do a re-index. But, doing a re-index totally depends on the application use case and the number of records you have in it. If the reason for removing the index was due to lack of usage then there is no need for you to do re-index since no is going to search on them. The old indexes will take some space but it should be fine. Also, be careful when you are doing re-indexing because it highly depends on the number of documents you have. If you have somewhere around 10M and above I would **NOT recommend** re-indexing as it is CPU & I/O bound operation. If the number of documents are less then you can surely go ahead and do it.